# Tkinter doesn’t show the window in my game

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m making a simple game where some random number is shown on the window for 1 second. When it dissapears, I ask the user what number it was on the command line (I have to do it like this because it’s an exercise). If it’s wrong, print some message and original number to the window, if it’s right, print there "NICE". I’m new to tkinter so sorry if this is some obvious mistake.

First, only the first version of the window was showed, so I tried to get around it by putting the code into a function and calling it 1 second later, so the mainloop gets executed, but it doesn’t work. It was kinda random attempt. I couldn’t find anything on google, I didn’t even know what to do at that point, so this is my last chance. Now my program asks for the guess first and then shows the winning/losing mesage without showing the number first. The code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Guessing game")
window.geometry("600x400")


def guessing_game():
    number = random.randint(10000, 100000)
    
    text = tk.Label(window, text=number, font=("Times New Roman", 50))
    text.place(x=300, y=200, anchor="center")
    window.after(1000, lambda: text.destroy())
    
    guess = int(input("What was my number? "))
    if guess == number:
        winning_message = tk.Label(window, text="NICE", font=("Times New Roman", 50))
        winning_message.place(x=300, y=200, anchor="center")
    else:
        losing_message = tk.Label(window, text=f"Wrong, my number was {number}.", font=("Times New Roman", 30))
        losing_message.place(x=300, y=200, anchor="center")


window.after(1000, guessing_game())
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just curious what is the point in guessing number between 10000 and 100000?

Comment: @Alderven: My guess is whey want a 5 digit number, and haven't figured out how to add leading zeroes for numbers <10,000.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.

Firstly, you're calling the guessing_game function immediately with `window.after(1000, guessing_game())`, instead of passing it as a function reference with `window.after(1000, guessing_game)`. This means that the guessing_game function is executed right away and not after 1 second.

Secondly, the input function blocks the execution of the program until the user enters a value, which means that the program is paused until the user enters a guess. You could try using an Entry widget instead:

```
guess_entry = tk.Entry(window)
guess_entry.place(x=300, y=300, anchor="center")
guess_entry.focus()  # set focus to the entry widget

def check_guess():
    guess = int(guess_entry.get())
    if guess == number:
        winning_message = tk.Label(window, text="NICE", font=("Times New Roman", 50))
        winning_message.place(x=300, y=200, anchor="center")
    else:
        losing_message = tk.Label(window, text=f"Wrong, my number was {number}.", font=("Times New Roman", 30))
        losing_message.place(x=300, y=200, anchor="center")
```

Comment: line 14, in check_guess
    guess = int(guess_entry.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''